# How to use modal box with javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

[image]

I have a form where i update product details. As you can see on image, if the input 'Satış Fiyatı' (18.00) is bigger than the input down of it, i want to open modal box with confirmation. But i wan tto do this action after clicking submit button (Güncelle).

Shortly, i will click submit button, javascript will check if the value is bigger or not. If bigger it will open modal box with confrimation button. If not bigger directly will submit form without openning modal box.
[image]

And these are the codes i can open modal box when i click on submit now:

```
<input type="button" name="btn" value="Güncelle" id="submitBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-submit" class="btn btn-default btn-success" />

<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-submit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            Emin misiniz?
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            Ürüne ait satış fiyatı, alış fiyatından düşük..!!
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">İptal</button>
        <a href="#" id="submit" class="btn btn-success success">Tamam</a>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>


<script>
$('#submitBtn').click(function() {

 $('#lname').text($('#lastname').val());
 $('#fname').text($('#firstname').val());
 });

$('#submit').click(function(){
$('#formfield').submit();
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#submitBtn').click(function(){
    if($("#Satış_Fiyatı_id").val()>hiddenVal){
         $("#confirm-submit").modal("show");
    }else{
          //submit your code here
  }    
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. @Dilip